# How to expand several accordion headings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm using U.S Web Design Standards Accordion in my project. However, I don't find functionality that will allow me to expand several accordion headings at once. Is there a separate JavaScript I can write on top of it to enable desired functionality?
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0mrdvw3w/

```
<ul class="usa-accordion">
<li>
<button class="usa-accordion-button"
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="amendment-1">
First Amendment
</button>
<div id="amendment-1" class="usa-accordion-content">
<p>
- Some text - Some text - Some text -
</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<button class="usa-accordion-button"
aria-controls="amendment-2">
Second Amendment
</button>
<div id="amendment-2" class="usa-accordion-content">
<p>
- Some text - Some text - Some text -
</div>
</li>
<li>
```

Comment: Are you trying to allow more than 1 to be expanded together, or expand all 3 at the same time with a single click?

Answer (score 0):

Now don't quote me on this, but I believe the accordion is meant to only show 1 panel at a time, so I don't think it will work with what you want to do. However, you can use jQuery to create your own if all you want to do show the panel when the user clicks on it. You can use jQuery's `slideToggle()`.

I'd do something like this:

```
<ul class="usa-accordion">
    <li>
      <button class="usa-accordion-button"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="amendment-1">
        First Amendment
      </button>
      <div id="amendment-1" class="content">
        <p>
        Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then:

```
$(".content").hide();

$(".usa-accordion-button").click(function() {

    $(this).next().slideToggle(function() {

        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            // change icon to '-'
        } else {
            // change icon to '+'
        }
    });

});
```

***DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yibixoxoru/edit?html,js,output***

Comment: Thanks for your input! This works great! The only thing, is how do I keep expand/collapse (+/-) icons consistent with the expanded content just like on this page https://standards.usa.gov/accordions/. It looks like when I add JavaScript code, icons are not appearing the right way.

Comment: @webIra7 Just updated the answer along with the jsbin. You would need to add a callback function that runs after the toggle completes. In the function, you just check to see whether it's currently visible or not to determine which icon to show.

Comment: I'm using the following java script code to enable aria-expanded as it's directly connected to css which enables the right icon to appear, but it applies to all of the accordion panels (expanded and collapsed). Is their a way to apply it only to those that are opened? if($(this.is(":visible")) {$(button.usa-accordion-button").attr("aria-expanded","true");}else{ $(button.usa-accordion-button").attr("aria-expanded","false");

Comment: the problem is that it applies to all buttons instead of the active one. When you expand container all icons are displayed with minus (-), Do you have any advice on how to resolve it?

Comment: If I were you, I'd store an ```id``` with each button that is correlated with the ```id``` of the accordion container. Then, in your logic, instead of targeting ```$(button.usa-accordion-button")```, you'll target the button with the ```id``` that the current container has.